# How to count the same value occurences in arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, count

Here is the snippet of code where I want to find the multiple occurrences of animal name.

I have written the code comparing the list indexes, but unable understand how to compare the names and count the number of occurrences of each name.

```
        List<Animals> animalList= new ArrayList<Animals>();

        try {
            CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall(callProcedure, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                    ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

            boolean results = stmt.execute();

            if (results) {
                ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
                int count = 0;
                while (rs.next()) {

                    Animals animal = new Animals();

                    animal.setAnimalName(rs.getString("animal_name"));
                    animal.setAge(rs.getString("age"));
                    animal.setHealth(rs.getString("health"));
                    animalList.add(animal);
                    count++;             
                }
            }

            int nbOccurences = 1;

            for (int i = 0, length = animalList.size(); i < length; i++) {
                if (i < length - 1) {
                    if (animalList.get(i) == animalList.get(i+1)) {
                        nbOccurences++;
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println( animalList.get(i) + " occurs " + nbOccurences
                                    + " time(s)"); //end of array
                }

                if (i < length - 1 && animalList.get(i) != animalList.get(i+1)) {
                    System.out.println( animalList.get(i) + " occurs " + nbOccurences
                                    + " time(s)"); //moving to new element in array
                    nbOccurences = i;
                }

            }

        } catch (SQLException sqlE) {
            sqlE.printStackTrace();
        }

        return animalList;
```

Comment: First, you should remember the difference between == and "equals()" in Java, and then you should not compare on animalsList.get(x) but on something like  animalsList.get(x).getAnimalName() because you want to find multiple occurrences of animal name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution, IMHO would be to stream the animal list, group by the name and count:

```
Map<String, Long> nameCount = 
    animalList.stream()
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Animal::getName, 
                                             Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution.!!